# windows ProductPolicy key enum/constants

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

i'm reading windows internals and found the productoptions/productpolicy key, i know it is a switch in tokens.dat but don't know how to decrypt it or if there is a decrypted version of it

also did not find any documentation of the constants or the enum for the product policy key

first of all, is this information public ? do i have to set 10 virtual machines to get the key for each windows version or does anyone know the answer to that ?

Comment: [Having fun with Windows Licensing](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/06/15/having-fun-with-windows-licensing/) shows how to decode the key.

Comment: Hehe, I will if you think it **competely** answers your question, that was very fast to read the whole article ;)

Comment: yeah partially answer the part where i ask for the structure or the meaning of the key, that was full structure in the link, so yeah it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I cannot find any documentation of the constants or the enum for the product policy key

The article referenced below reverse engineers the binary value contained in the key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\ProductOptions`.

It also includes a program (with source code) to decode the key.

---

#### Having fun with Windows Licensing

> If you look into the registry in the key
>   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\ProductOptions you will find several
>   licensing related Values.
>
> The ProductType and ProductSuite keys contain the OS Suite and
>   Edition, but the ProductPolicy key is much more interesting. So let’s
>   have a closer look at it
>
> ...
>
> As you can see the license names are there as a Unicode string and
>   later on I will show you how we can read the values. But because I
>   didn’t want to extract all the names manually I decided to see if I
>   could reverse the used structure because it didn’t look very
>   complicated
>
> ...
>
> It starts with a header:
>
> ```
>   TProductPolicyHeader = packed record
>     cbSize: DWORD;
>     cbDataSize: DWORD;
>     cbEndMarker: DWORD;
>     Unknown1: DWORD;
>     Unknown2: DWORD;
>   end;
> ```
>
> then an array of values follows:
>
> ```
>   TProductPolicyValue = packed record
>     cbSize: Word;
>     cbName: Word;
>     SlDatatype: Word;
>     cbData: Word;
>     Unknown1: DWORD;
>     Unknown2: DWORD;
>   end;
> ```
>
> The SlDataType is a word value that corresponds to the values of the
>   0SLDATATYPE enum:
>
> ```
>   _tagSLDATATYPE =
>   (
>     SL_DATA_NONE       = REG_NONE,
>     SL_DATA_SZ         = REG_SZ,
>     SL_DATA_DWORD      = REG_DWORD,
>     SL_DATA_BINARY     = REG_BINARY,
>     SL_DATA_MULTI_SZ   = REG_MULTI_SZ,
>     SL_DATA_SUM        = 100
>   );
>   SLDATATYPE = _tagSLDATATYPE;
>   TSlDataType = SLDATATYPE;
>   PSlDataType = ^SLDATATYPE;
> ```
>
> And we end with an End Marker (of size cbEndMarker).

Source [Having fun with Windows Licensing](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/06/15/having-fun-with-windows-licensing/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use **ProductPolicy Editor 1.5** to see all the values and their properties. Search for it on MDL (English and Chinese UI available).